# What is this usage of "have [Object] [Complement]?"

Tags: grammar

I hate Bush but I would rather **have** him **president** than Obama !

It is normal to expect it to be followed by a verb or past participle or present participle, but here it is not. is this archaic?

Comment: What do you mean by O and C? What is "it" referring to?

Comment: They appear to mean "object" and "complement" respectively.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'it' in your question. I assume you mean 'the word "have"'. Yes, 'have' is used as an auxiliary verb followed by V-pp to form perfect tenses, but here it is the main verb (we know that because it's the last verb in the verb group 'would rather have').

One possible but lesser used (and certainly not archaic) clause type in English is subject (here, 'I' - verb ('would rather have') - object ('him') - object complement ('president'). A simpler sentence is: 'They elected him president'. (In both sentences, is it also possible to say 'as president', and even possible to leave out 'president' - 'I would rather have him than Obama (as president, as next-door-neighbour etc)' and 'They elected him' (true, but my first question is going to be 'as what?')

If you said 'I would rather have elected him president', 'have' becomes an auxiliary verb and 'elected' is the main verb.

Comment: So it means, "I want to have Bush as President?"

Comment: It means: I would rather have Bush as president than I would have Obama (as president)."